# How to write styles to callouts wpf

Tags: wpf, styles

I'm using the next namespace (http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/drawing).
I've two controls for the collout which use the same styles.
i want to write some reusable style for those two controls, but no success...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reuse styles, whether it's for callouts or any other control, by making them resources and referencing them later. For example:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ed="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/drawing"
    x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MyCalloutStyle" TargetType="ed:Callout">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Orange" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <ed:Callout Style="{StaticResource MyCalloutStyle}" />
        <ed:Callout Style="{StaticResource MyCalloutStyle}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```